# "requires a detailed scientific justification" or "requires detailed scientific justification"

Tags: articles

> The use of a different reference drug requires **a** detailed scientific justification, as well as additional documents and data.

The word "justification" is marked as both countable and uncountable in dictionaries, and I'm not sure whether **a** is necessary here.

Maybe it works both ways, with or without "**a**"? I feel like with "requires" it works both ways, while with "calls for" it feels like "**a**" is necessary.

> The use of a different reference drug calls for **a** detailed scientific justification, as well as additional documents and data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **justification** is an uncountable noun when it means

> *the action of showing something to be right or reasonable* ‘Such a position is, I suppose, formally possible but it - and not extrapolation - requires special justification.’

but it is countable when it means

> *good reason for something that exists or has been done*-‘all these incidents were used again as a justification for my sacking’

My source was:[www.en.oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com).

Therefore,I would not use the article **a**.